# Adding value to Arraylist<ArrayList> Resets the other values to that added value

Tags: java, list, debugging, arraylist, minecraft

So i have an Arraylist Containing Arraylist. Whenever i add a new arraylist to that it will reset all the other arraylists it contains to that arraylist i latest added. I have no idea why this happens ive been trying to figure this out for days...

Heres the arraylist. `static ArrayList<ArrayList<BlockPos>> Directions = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BlockPos>>();`

Heres the code where it adds the ArrayLists to the ArrayList.

```
    public static void CalculateEveryPath() {
    //Calculate path to every direction.
    BlockPos Start = new BlockPos(mc.player.posX, mc.player.posY, mc.player.posZ);
    BlockPos Goal = null;
    int ArrayDir = 0;
    
    if (Dir1 == false) {
        //+X
        Goal = new BlockPos(Start.add(350, 0, 0));
        ArrayDir = 1;
    } else if (Dir2 == false) {
        //-X
        Goal = new BlockPos(Start.add(-350, 0, 0));
        ArrayDir = 2;
    } else if (Dir3 == false) {
        //+Z
        Goal = new BlockPos(Start.add(0, 0, 300));
        ArrayDir = 3;
    } else if (Dir4 == false) {
        //-Z
        Goal = new BlockPos(Start.add(0, 0, -350));
        ArrayDir = 4;
    }
    
    if (Goal != null) {
        ArrayList<BlockPos> Dir = new ArrayList<BlockPos>();
        Dir = AStar.GetPath(Start, Goal, 350, false, true);
        Dir = AStar.GetPath(Start, AStar.Closest, 450, false, true);
        if (Dir.isEmpty()) {
            Dir.add(Start);
        }
         
        if (ArrayDir == 1) {
            Directions.add(Dir);
            Renderer.PositionsYellow.addAll(Directions.get(0));
            Dir1 = true;
        } else if (ArrayDir == 2) {
            //Adds Dir array to Directions. BUT RESETS THE ALL THE OTHER ARRAYS TO THAT VALUE!
            Directions.add(Dir);
            Renderer.PositionsYellow.addAll(Directions.get(1));
            Dir2 = true;
        } else if (ArrayDir == 3) {
            //Adds Dir array to Directions. BUT RESETS THE ALL THE OTHER ARRAYS TO THAT VALUE!
            Directions.add(Dir);
            Renderer.PositionsYellow.addAll(Directions.get(2));
            Dir3 = true;
        } else if (ArrayDir == 4) {
            //Adds Dir array to Directions. BUT RESETS THE ALL THE OTHER ARRAYS TO THAT VALUE!
            Directions.add(Dir);
            Renderer.PositionsYellow.addAll(Directions.get(3));
            Dir4 = true;
        }
    }
}
```

So basicly whenever i add a new arraylist to it it just resets all the other arraylists to that value. Anyone have idea why this happens? Or is this a bug in my java or something. (The AStar has nothing to do with the array it just returns an array containing Blockpositions.)

Comment: `Dir = new ArrayList<BlockPos>(); Dir = AStar.GetPath(Start, Goal, 350, false, true);        Dir = AStar.GetPath(Start, AStar.Closest, 450, false, true);` - those 3 assignments overwrite each other. I'm quite sure that's not what you wanted to do here.

Comment: I did want to do that the Astar looks for the best path then it will rewrite the path with the closest position it got to when looking for the actual path. It works fine no problem there its just adding those values to the arrays where the issue is.

Comment: I don't see anything that could be wrong in the code you provided. It has to be something in your other methods, maybe in AStar. My guess is that some variable is static and you just modify that one instance.

Comment: Considering that you call `AStar.GetPath` multiple times in a succession and claim that it does what it is supposed then I'm guessing that one call is dependent on the previous one - there is some state / static variables.

Comment: The AStar does work i add the blockpositions to another 1 list that renders all the paths it gave it works fine returns the paths like its supposed to. Also if i add a System.out.print to the Array its trying to add to the other array it gives correct result. The problem is that adding that to the array resets all the other values it had. Also I tried to do this with 4 SEPERATE array lists and it still happened. it doesnt make any sense. i had this same issue before when dealing with many arraylists it might be a bug or corruption in my java or something

Comment: Sorry but we can't really help you with the code you provided - it seems fine to me. The problem must be in some other part of your code. And trust me, there's a lot of people using `add()` method on collections, if there's some bug then you won't be the first person to encounter it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was the issue. Some corruption in Astar when i call that method it clears an array in the class it has nothing to do with these arrays in this class but somehow after it clears it it also clears that array in this class. Basicly instead of using .clear for that array i just did Array = new Arraylist to clear it that way. So wierd some bug or something. If you have this same issue try locating exactlt where it gets messed up.